# Is there a better way to structure this code with inheritance?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

My code is organised as follows:

```
run_experiment.py
base_model.py
models/
  model_1.py
  model_2.py
  ...
```

Each model inherits from `base_model`. The code always runs from `run_experiment.py`, which instantiates a model like this:

```
from importlib import import_module

def run_experiment(module_name, model_name):
    model = getattr(import_module("models." + module_name), model_name)()
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_experiment('model_1', 'ModelOne')
```

The model classes look like this:

```
from base_model import BaseModel

class ModelOne(BaseModel):
    ...
```

Note that my linter marks that first import as missing, since `base_model` isn't adjacent to `model_1.py` (so it should be `from .base_model import BaseModel`), but it only works *without* the period, since the code runs from the directory above (`run_experiment.py`)

This whole structure feels excessively complicated. Is there a better, more Pythonic way to do this?

(Moved from codereview.stackexchange, since this code is incomplete.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from ..base_model import BaseModel` since it's in the directory above? It would probably make more sense for `base_model.py` to be in the `models` directory though